# Is there a way in Excel to sort cells based on cell style?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a simple workout tracker using Excel. I want to track the amount of repetitions I do with modified versions of the workout. For example I have the data set of:

12, **16**, 14, 20, **18**

Those would be the amount of push ups I did each day. The bold days I did diamond pushups. By the end I wanted to compute the amount of repetitions I did of diamond push ups. Would it be possible to add them together based on their cell style?

Comment: Formatting should not contain information. Create a second column called "Pushup Type" and populate that.

Comment: we can get the property of formatting of the cell via VBA functions in Macro: Range().cells().[our property name] and then sort it in Macro. But probably it is not worth it because we can just create scond column with the type of push ups

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you'd want a second column and call it Type(?) then put next to it, Diamond Push up, then just filter that.

If not you can do it the harder way by this:

Select your entire Data (Entire Column),
Control+H (To bring up Replace Window),
Options,
Format,
Under Find what, Choose Format from Cell (Select a cell which has the Bold text in it),
Under Replace with, Choose Format, chuck on a pretty background color,
Then Filter with background color.